# Remove unwanted Url variable when WooCommerce is active in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, caching, woocommerce, geolocation

I've been facing some issues lately with our new business website. Basically, when the homepage is loaded `www.motionitalia.it` it looks like to redirect to another page `https://www.motionitalia.it/?v=e0c86157e86f`. I've asked a friend and he suggested that it might be related to the cache.

I tested the website using Site Health's tool called diagnostic mode and I deactivated all the plugins. It turned out that the ?v=e0c86157e86f appears when I activate Woocommerce.

I would like to remove it from the URL because it slows down the website and it doesn't even look professional. Has anyone of you ever experienced it? If so, could you suggest to me a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to WooCommerce **geolocation with page caching support enabled**

To disable `?v=e0c86157e86f` like from WordPress Urls when WooCommerce plugin is active, Go to WooCommerce Settings > General *(tab)*, then for **"Default customer location"** select **"Geolocate"** instead of *"Geolocate (with page caching support)"*, then save.

[image]

As you will see, the Urls are now clean without `?v=e0c86157e86f` like.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It worked! I've been struggling with it for weeks! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: This could mess up caching if you're not careful - see: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-remove-vxxxx-string-from-wordpress-urls/